# Questions that feel like spam

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam, help-improvement, external-links

In the last couple of weeks I've noticed a number of questions in the Help and Improvement queue that just don't quite feel right; they have external URLs and questions like "How can I do something like this?" or "How can I get something to happen on this site?"

[Here is a recent example (10k link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130089/how-do-i-make-a-embedded-stream-switch-on-click), and looking at the two links, the first seems to be a image hosting site, but the second requires a login.

[Here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105688/wordpress-category-rollover), with a URL shortener leading to a commercial site.

I flagged both as low quality, but am I being over-suspicious? Not suspicious enough? Should I just "Skip"?

Comment: Myeah, those ring all sorts of alarm bells.

Comment: Meh, spammers don't usually force you to login.  Probably best to assume that a link to an external site inside the question give the SE engine *lots* of reason to put a question in a Triage queue.  You can yell at the screen for a bit about the wisdom of the queue reviewers to promote it into H&I.

Comment: I clicked the link to the spam examples posted above.   I wouldn't have if they hadn't been.  Have I been meta-spammed?

Answer (score 33):

These are just low quality questions, lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Instead, they link to some site that they think illustrates what they want or demonstrates the problem they want to solve.

These are *not spam*, because they are not trying to sell or promote anything. Nothing in the post tells you to go check out their great site, or tell you how you can work from home and earn gazillions. Note that links on posts start out with a *no follow* attribute, so there is not page rank juice to gain from including a link in a Stack Overflow post (no-follow can be removed for popular high-quality posts, the criteria for which are deliberately not disclosed).

If you do flag these as spam all that'll happen is that a moderator will decline the flag and perhaps just close the post to put it out of its misery (if they have the time).

These posts require a MCVE; if you cannot create one in the H&I queue (and I can imagine you cannot be bothered to if the OP did not), send the post back to Triage.

Comment: Hi Martijn -- what's your opinion (if any) on [this self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133197/i-need-new-title-tag-and-meta-description-character-lengths) that seems to mostly just be a link to a blog about SEO. I consider it spam, but don't think it's *obvious* enough -- and I'm confused how it has managed to gather upvotes from the community?

Comment: @TZHX: that smells off to me too. I'll investigate and / or pass it on to the Community Managers team for deeper inspection.

Comment: Is it just my lack of Rep that prevents me from seeing the example question(s) linked to by @TZHX ?  (I see the red, underlined link in his comment, but it takes me to the 'question removed for reasons of moderation...' page.)   Is there a state other than removed that questions can be permanently assigned so they remain as examples to support these meta questions?

Comment: @JasonInVegas They're deleted, so you have to have 10k rep to see them.